# Why Matplotlib plot the wrong heatmap in this case?

Tags: numpy, histogram2d

"m" is an GPS coordinates array defined in https://www.dropbox.com/s/vua4nakd8sz3ocy/data.py?dl=0

I can use the matplotlib function

```
hist2d(zip(*m)[0],zip(*m)[1], bins=60, cmap='jet', normed=True)
```

to produce the correct density heatmap.

However, if I use this way:

```
x,y = zip(*m)[:2]
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=50)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
clf()
scatter(x,y,c='k')
imshow(heatmap, extent=extent, cmap='jet')
```

It produces the obviously wrong heatmap. Why this happen?

[wrong.img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVLD0.png)

The black points are the GPS points.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! histogram2d in numpy uses abscissa and ordinate system in order to be consistent with histogramdd in numpy. So the correct one should be:

```
x,y = zip(*m)[:2]
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(y,x,bins=40) 
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
scatter(x,y,c='k')
imshow(heatmap[::-1], extent=extent,cmap='jet',interpolation='nearest')
```

Anyway, this is not recommended.